# Improved reduce0 CUDA reduction code not working

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have written a CUDA code that basically sums an array for me. THe array size `N` should be a power of of `2`, namely, `2^x`. However, my code is not working properly. For example, if the output is `150177410`, my code outputs `150177408`. I have been trying to debug this for the past `5` hours. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the code:

```
//only for array size of 2^x and TPB of 2^y as godata is = num of blocks. But num of blocks 2^sth if previous satisfied
//Works for arbitrary size array of type 2^x


#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void computeAddShared(int *in , int *out, int sizeInput){
    //not made parameters gidata and godata to emphasize that parameters get copy of address and are different from pointers in host code
    extern __shared__ float temp[];

    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    temp[ltid] = 0;
    while(tid < sizeInput){
        temp[ltid] += in[tid];
        tid+=gridDim.x * blockDim.x; // to handle array of any size
    }
    __syncthreads();
    int offset = 1;
    while(offset < blockDim.x){
        if(ltid % (offset * 2) == 0){
            temp[ltid] = temp[ltid] + temp[ltid + offset];
        }
        __syncthreads();
        offset*=2;
    }
    if(ltid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = temp[0];
    }

}

int main(){



    int N = 8192;//should be 2^sth
    int size = N;
    int *a = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    /* TO create random number
    FILE *f;
        f = fopen("invertedList.txt" , "w");
        a[0] = 1 + (rand() % 8);
        fprintf(f, "%d,",a[0]);
        for( int i = 1 ; i< N; i++){
            a[i] = a[i-1] + (rand() % 8) + 1;
            fprintf(f, "%d,",a[i]);
        }
        fclose(f);
        return 0;*/
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("invertedList.txt","r");
    if( f == NULL){
            printf("File not found\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
    }
    int count = 0 ;
    long actualSum = 0;
    for( int i =0 ; i < N ; i++){
        fscanf(f, "%d,", &a[count]);
        actualSum+=a[count];
        count++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("The actual sum is %d\n",actualSum);
    int* gidata;
    int* godata;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gidata, N* sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(gidata,a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int TPB  = 256;
    int blocks = 10; //to get things kicked off
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    while(blocks != 1 ){
        if(size < TPB){
            TPB  = size; // size is 2^sth
        }
        blocks  = (size+ TPB -1 ) / TPB;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&godata, blocks * sizeof(int));
        computeAddShared<<<blocks, TPB,TPB*sizeof(int)>>>(gidata, godata,size);
        //cudaFree(gidata);
        gidata = godata;
        size = blocks;
    }
    //printf("The error by cuda is %s",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));


    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float elapsedTime; 
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
    printf("time is %f ms", elapsedTime);
    int *output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(output, gidata,size *  sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //Cant free either earlier as both point to same location
    cudaError_t chk = cudaFree(godata);
    if(chk!=0){
        printf("First chk also printed error. Maybe error in my logic\n");
    }

    printf("The error by threadsyn is %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    printf("The sum of the array is %d\n", output[0]);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens as you step the input domain down in size? The pattern of errors might be helpful in diagnosis.

Comment: Is it really necessary to post code which relies on an external file we don't have access to and which includs 10s of lines of redundant commented out code and 130+ column wide lines containing nothing but menaingless comments?

Comment: I am surprised that it gives any answer at all! you are checking that `offset < blockDim.x` as it should be `ltid+offset < blockDim.x`. In the second while loop you are using a shared memory that is not yours. EDIT: and the dynamic `__shared__` size won't do any good because you are using `temp[ltid] = 0;` So only a shared memory with the size of the block is valid.

Comment: I think the reduction kernel itself, while unorthodox, is actually OK, as is the rather odd looking host loop calling the kernel (you only ever need to call any reduction like this *twice*, so why use a loop?). But there is at least a host side buffer overflow in `cudaMemcpy(output, gidata,size *  sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` and possibly other bugs, but because no one can actually run this code, I am not sure how you expect anyone could actually answer this question...

Answer (score 1):

As said in advance by talonmies, the kernel itself is OK. Basically, it is the `reduce0` kernel of the CUDA SDK improved with *algorithm cascading* in the sense of *Brent's optimization* used when improving the `reduce5` kernel to `reduce6` of the same SDK.

That the kernel works correctly can be shown by the following test code, which also compares the performance of `reduce0` with that of the OP's kernel, named `reduce0_stackoverflow` in the code. The `reduce0_stackoverflow` kernel also reports, commented, the corresponding code lines of `reduce0`.

For the test case below, `reduce0_stackoverflow` executes in `0.030ms` as compared to `0.049ms` on a GeForce GT540M card.

Please, notice that the code below does not require that the array size must be a power of `2`.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getchar(); exit(code); }
    }
}

/*******************************************************/
/* CALCULATING THE NEXT POWER OF 2 OF A CERTAIN NUMBER */
/*******************************************************/
unsigned int nextPow2(unsigned int x)
{
    --x;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return ++x;
}

/*************************************/
/* CHECK IF A NUMBER IS A POWER OF 2 */
/*************************************/
bool isPow2(unsigned int x)
{
    return ((x&(x-1))==0);
}

/******************/
/* REDUCE0 KERNEL */
/******************/
/* This reduction interleaves which threads are active by using the modulo
    operator.  This operator is very expensive on GPUs, and the interleaved
    inactivity means that no whole warps are active, which is also very
    inefficient */
template <class T>
__global__ void reduce0(T *g_idata, T *g_odata, unsigned int N)
{
    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    unsigned int tid    = threadIdx.x;                              // Local thread index
    unsigned int i      = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    // Global thread index

    // --- Loading data to shared memory
    sdata[tid] = (i < N) ? g_idata[i] : 0;

    // --- Before going further, we have to make sure that all the shared memory loads have been completed
    __syncthreads();

    // --- Reduction in shared memory
    for (unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2)
    {
        // --- Only the threads with index multiple of 2*s perform additions. Furthermore, modulo arithmetic is slow.       
        if ((tid % (2*s)) == 0) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s]; }
        // --- At the end of each iteration loop, we have to make sure that all memory operations have been completed
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // --- Write result for this block to global memory. At the end of the kernel, global memory will contain the results for the summations of
    //     individual blocks
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

/***************************/
/* REDUCE0 - STACKOVERFLOW */
/***************************/
template <class T>
__global__ void reduce0_stackoverflow(T *g_idata , T *g_odata, unsigned int N) {

    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    unsigned int tid    = threadIdx.x;                              // Local thread index
    unsigned int i      = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    // Global thread index

    // --- Loading data to shared memory
    //sdata[tid] = (i < N) ? g_idata[i] : 0;                        // CUDA SDK
    sdata[tid] = 0;
    while(i < N){
        sdata[tid] += g_idata[i];
        i+=gridDim.x * blockDim.x; // to handle array of any size
    }

    // --- Before going further, we have to make sure that all the shared memory loads have been completed
    __syncthreads();

    // --- Reduction in shared memory
    //  for (unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2)                  // CUDA SDK
    //  {
    //     if ((tid % (2*s)) == 0) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s]; }
    //     __syncthreads();
    //  }
    unsigned int s = 1;
    while(s < blockDim.x) 
    {
        // --- Only the threads with index multiple of 2*s perform additions. Furthermore, modulo arithmetic is slow.       
        if ((tid % (2*s)) == 0) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s]; }

        // --- At the end of each iteration loop, we have to make sure that all memory operations have been completed
        __syncthreads();

        s*=2;
    }

    // --- Write result for this block to global memory. At the end of the kernel, global memory will contain the results for the summations of
    //     individual blocks
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int N = 15336;

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(N,3);

    int NumThreads  = (N < BLOCKSIZE) ? nextPow2(N) : BLOCKSIZE;
    int NumBlocks   = (N + NumThreads - 1) / NumThreads;

    // when there is only one warp per block, we need to allocate two warps
    // worth of shared memory so that we don't index shared memory out of bounds
    int smemSize = (NumThreads <= 32) ? 2 * NumThreads * sizeof(int) : NumThreads * sizeof(int);

    // --- Creating events for timing
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec_block(NumBlocks);

    /***********/
    /* REDUCE0 */
    /***********/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    reduce0<<<NumBlocks, NumThreads, smemSize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec_block.data()), N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("reduce0 - Elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);   

    // --- The last part of the reduction, which would be expensive to perform on the device, is executed on the host
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec_block(d_vec_block);
    int sum_reduce0 = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NumBlocks; i++) sum_reduce0 = sum_reduce0 + h_vec_block[i];
    printf("Result for reduce0 = %i\n",sum_reduce0);

    /**********************************/
    /* REDUCE0 KERNEL - STACKOVERFLOW */
    /**********************************/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    reduce0_stackoverflow<<<NumBlocks/2, NumThreads, smemSize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec_block.data()), N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("reduce0 - stackoverflow - Elapsed time:  %3.3f ms \n", time);   

    // --- The last part of the reduction, which would be expensive to perform on the device, is executed on the host
    h_vec_block = d_vec_block;
    int sum_reduce0_stackoverflow = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NumBlocks; i++) sum_reduce0_stackoverflow = sum_reduce0_stackoverflow + h_vec_block[i];
    printf("Result for reduce0_stackoverflow = %i\n",sum_reduce0_stackoverflow);

    getchar();
}
```